# How to get totalcount in Paging Toolbar count- EXTJS

Tags: extjs

I am trying to find out the totalcount to disable button based on this.

First time i am trying out with ext.js,Let me know if i am going wrong.

Just i need is to get the totalcount ofdata

Here is my code

```
Ext.define('MyTeckno.view.Users', {
extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',

initComponent : function() {
    var me = this;

    me.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
        callback : me,
        proxy : {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'users.json',
            pageSize: 25,
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'results.records',
                totalProperty:  'totalCount',
                successProperty: 'success'
            }
        },
        fields : [
            'userid', 'name', 'email', 'phone'
        ],
        tools: [
            {
                xtype: 'checkbox',
                itemId: 'showAllCheckbox',
                boxLabel: 'Show All',
                listeners: {
                    change: {
                        fn: me.onShowAllChange,
                        scope: me
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        listeners : {
            beforeload : {
                fn : me.onUserStoreBeforeLoad,
                scope : me
            }
        }
    });

    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ];

    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
        store: me.store,   // same store GridPanel is using
        dock: 'bottom',
        displayInfo: true
    }];

    me.callParent(arguments);

    me.store.load();
},

onUserStoreBeforeLoad: function(store, operation, options) {
    var me = this;

//If showall is checked set the totalcount if not set the default 25
// Assumption is that you are getting the totalCount as for the firstload
    var isShowAll = me.down('#showAllCheckbox').getValue();

    if(isShowAll) {
        store.pageSize = store.totalCount;
    }
    else {
        store.pageSize = 25;
    }
},

//Change event on showall checkbox, just call the store.load() to reload the store
onShowAllChange: function() {
    var me = this;

    me.store.load();
}

});
```

Assume that another call to your server to get the totalCount and set it to the pageSize

Can any one help me on this please

Comment: What is your ExtJS version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the store.totalCount property has the total of records returned on the last request. But I believe this is not the right approach. Here's what doc says about [pagingtoolbar](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging.html):

> As the number of records increases, the time required for the browser
> to render them increases. Paging is used to reduce the amount of data
> exchanged with the client. Note: if there are more records/rows than
> can be viewed in the available screen area, vertical scrollbars will
> be added.
>
> Paging is typically handled on the server side (see exception below).
> The client sends parameters to the server side, which the server needs
> to interpret and then respond with the appropriate data.
>
> Ext.toolbar.Paging is a specialized toolbar that is bound to a
> Ext.data.Store and provides automatic paging control. This Component
> loads blocks of data into the store by passing parameters used for
> paging criteria.

In this case, you request that the server return only the quantity that you want to display (unchecked checkbox) or all information (checked checkbox).

Knowing this, do you agree that it does not make much sense to change the pageSize with the amount of data coming in the last request? This amount may be out of date if changes have occurred since the last request.

It would be more interesting to adapt the serverside, returning all the data when the checkbox is checked, or following the pagination (parameters start and limit).

I created this fiddle to exemplify: [Extjs Grid Pagination](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ob0).

Also take a look at the file Data/users.json.

Here's what doc says about [store.pageSize property](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/api/Ext.data.Store.html#cfg-pageSize):

> The number of records considered to form a 'page'. This is used to
> power the built-in paging using the nextPage and previousPage
> functions when the grid is paged using a Ext.toolbar.Paging Defaults
> to 25.
>
> To disable paging, set the pageSize to 0.

Do not forget that the server should always return total records (`totalCount`) so that `pagingtootbar` can mount the paging correctly.

The `proxy.setExtraParam` adds the parameter to the proxy. This causes the parameter to be sent wherever the store loads.

Extjs code:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    pageSize: 10,
    //pageSizeDefault avoid a hardcode below (line 49)
    pageSizeDefault: 10,
    proxy : {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'users.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'root',
            totalProperty:  'totalCount', //<= This should be returned from the backend
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    },
    fields : [
        'userid', 'name', 'email', 'phone'
    ],
    listeners: {
        load: function(store){
            console.log('totalCount => ', store.getTotalCount());
        }
    }
});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    title: 'Teste',
    autoLoad: true,
    tools: [
        {
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            itemId: 'showAllCheckbox',
            boxLabel: 'Show All',
            listeners: {
                change: {
                    fn: function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                        var store = field.up('grid').getStore();

                        //If showall is checked set the totalcount if not set the default 25
                        // Assumption is that you are getting the totalCount as for the firstload
                        if(newValue) {
                            store.setPageSize(0);
                            store.getProxy().setExtraParam('limit', 0);
                        }else {
                            store.setPageSize(store.pageSizeDefault);
                            store.getProxy().setExtraParam('limit', store.pageSizeDefault);
                        }

                        store.reload();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', flex: 3},
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
        store: store,   // same store GridPanel is using
        dock: 'bottom',
        displayInfo: true,
        items:[
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                handler: function(){
                    alert('click');
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
});

var wnd = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
    layout:'fit',
    maximized: true,
    title: 'Example of pagination'
}).show();

wnd.add(grid);
```

Backend code example:

```
var data = [
    {userid: "1", name: "user1", email: "user1@email.com", phone: "+55999999991"},
    {userid: "2", name: "user2", email: "user2@email.com", phone: "+55999999992"},
    {userid: "3", name: "user3", email: "user3@email.com", phone: "+55999999993"},
    {userid: "4", name: "user4", email: "user4@email.com", phone: "+55999999994"},
    {userid: "5", name: "user5", email: "user5@email.com", phone: "+55999999995"},
    {userid: "6", name: "user6", email: "user6@email.com", phone: "+55999999996"},
    {userid: "7", name: "user7", email: "user7@email.com", phone: "+55999999997"},
    {userid: "8", name: "user8", email: "user8@email.com", phone: "+55999999998"},
    {userid: "9", name: "user9", email: "user9@email.com", phone: "+55999999999"},
    {userid: "10", name: "user10", email: "user10@email.com", phone: "+55999999910"},
    {userid: "11", name: "user11", email: "user11@email.com", phone: "+55999999911"},
    {userid: "12", name: "user12", email: "user12@email.com", phone: "+55999999912"},
    {userid: "13", name: "user13", email: "user13@email.com", phone: "+55999999913"},
    {userid: "14", name: "user14", email: "user14@email.com", phone: "+55999999914"},
    {userid: "15", name: "user15", email: "user15@email.com", phone: "+55999999915"},
    {userid: "16", name: "user16", email: "user16@email.com", phone: "+55999999916"},
    {userid: "17", name: "user17", email: "user17@email.com", phone: "+55999999917"},
    {userid: "18", name: "user18", email: "user18@email.com", phone: "+55999999918"},
    {userid: "19", name: "user19", email: "user19@email.com", phone: "+55999999919"},
    {userid: "20", name: "user20", email: "user20@email.com", phone: "+55999999920"}
];

var totalCount = data.length;

if(params.limit > 0){
    data = data.slice(params.start, params.start + params.limit);
}

return {success: true, root: data, totalCount: totalCount};
```

To conclude, I would like to mention some observations that I think are important. I know you are starting with Extjs so please understand as a positive review:

- Avoid breaking class encapsulation. Notice that in the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ob0) I accessed the same `store.pageSize` property however, I used `store.getPageSize()` method instead of directly accessing the property. The same goes for `store.getTotalCount()`.
- Is it really necessary to give the user the option to bring all data (checkbox Show All), if the purpose of `pagingtoolbar` is precisely to reduce the amount of information carried, consequently reducing the time and computational consumption?
- I saw that in the `onUserStoreBeforeLoad` method, a property of the store is changed according to the value of the checkbox. It's interesting to analyze which component depends more on the other to know where to put the code. In this case, the checkbox changes the behavior of the store. This snippet could be inside the checkbox `change` method. In the current form, you would still need to remove the `onUserStoreBeforeLoad` method but, as suggested, deleting this component would not affect the code. It was clear?

Any questions, please comment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ob0

how to get totalcount in app.js??

Comment: can you please help me on this

Comment: how to console the count ??

Comment: Just get the store and call the getTotalCount method: `console.log(store.getTotalCount())`. If you want to simply check directly from the browser, I suggest using [Ext.ComponentQuery.query](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/api/Ext.ComponentQuery.html) like this: just open the Developer Tools, go to Console and put this: `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('<component selector>')[0].getStore().GetTotalCount()`. See the doc at the link above for more details.

Comment: getting 0 for console.log(store.getTotalCount()); can you please update in fiddle

Comment: Remember to return in the request the 'totalCount' property, thus: `{success: true, root: data, totalCount: totalCount};`. See the file Data/users.json.

I lost access to my fiddle account. Make a fork and add this snippet to the store:
`listeners: {load: function (store) {console.log('totalCount =>', store.getTotalCount()); }}`.
If you prefer I update my answer here with all the code.

Comment: yes please you can update the answer, it might be use full for others as well

Comment: I updated the answer. I added the listener that displays the totalCount on the console, after each store loading.

Comment: Thank you so much will try and get back to you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53933192/deselecting-the-checkbox-unchecks-all-the-records-but-selecting-the-header-check

Comment: can you pleae help me on this